# Using Harp with p5.js and coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, harp, p5.js

I am using harp (harpjs.com) and p5.js (p5js.org) and I would like to write everything in coffeescript.

Harp understands .coffee files, so I simply wrote a sketch.coffee but it didnt work. Renaming it to sketch.js worked, but I prefer .coffee. Do i need any special libraries to hook this up?

Answer (score 0):

Via http://harpjs.com/docs/development/coffeescript - if you include `<script src="sketch.js"></script>` in your html, and have a `sketch.coffee` file in the same directory, it should just work...